# Why semop() hangs?

Tags: c++, c, linux, semaphore

When trying run this code: At first it prints "Process `some_id` BEFORE enter" for each semaphor (2 times). Then it hangs. What is incorrect?

```
# include <sys/ipc.h>
# include <sys/sem.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <errno.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <iostream>

int seminit()
{
    key_t key = ftok("/bin", 1);
    int semid = semget (key, 1, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 600);
    if(-1 == semid)
        if(EEXIST == errno)
            semid = semget(key, 1, 0);
    return semid;
}

void uninit(int semid)
{
        semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID);
}

void semlock(int semid)
{
    struct sembuf p_buf;
    p_buf.sem_num = 0;
    p_buf.sem_op = -1;
    p_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    if(semop(semid, &p_buf, 1) == -1)
        printf("semlock failed: ERRNO: %d\n", errno);
}
void semunlock(int semid)
{
    struct sembuf v_buf;
    v_buf.sem_num = 0;
    v_buf.sem_op = 1;
    v_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    if(semop(semid, &v_buf, 1) == -1)
        printf("semunlock failed: ERRNO: %d\n", errno);
}
void some_function()
{
    int semid = seminit();
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    printf("Process %d BEFORE enter\n", pid);
    semlock(semid);
    printf("Process %d IN Critical section\n", pid);
    sleep(10);
    semunlock(semid);
    printf("Process %d AFTER leave\n", pid);
    uninit(semid);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        if(0 == fork())
            some_function();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: What is this code meant to do?  How do you expect it to work?  I am confused by main, which appears to fork once, and only do any work on the child process.

Comment: Ah I have mistaken, for operator will run from 0 to 1(edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that only a child is generated (I think that is not intended), still, I believe there is a missing wait before the return of the main process, which means that the main process will end faster than the child process and let it "hanged" (this can be part of the issue but is not maybe the hole issue, check that for cycle before).

Comment: +1 You are Right. But how should I wait until fork process end. I mean what function do this? (wait() doesn't work)

Comment: There are 2 types of wait functions described here: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl2_wait.htm  Seems that what you need is the waitpid() one, that receives a PID of a process and wait that process to end. Try to look a bit on that page. If you still have trouble, give a comment here. PS: Dont have my linux c stuff around :\